# Storing data from a mobile application

Tags: database, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find a simple solution to store user informations from a mobile application (ex: name, firstname, date, birthday, country, etc.) developed in Unity to visualize this data using Tableau.

I have tried, for example, looking at Firebase Realtime Database but it seems that I should avoid using NoSQL to avoid performance issues for an amount of data around 1GB or larger (https://community.tableau.com/thread/159812).

Knowing nothing at system administration and having some knowledge in SQL, which solution(s) would you advise me to use to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Database questions may be better answered at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you know some SQL, and you want simple and cheap solution - I would use MySQL and Php script on server, or REST from Unity.

Here's tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yq6dVdAed4c

And here you can find some examples how to use REST: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-rest-api-unity-part-1-what-rest-and-basic-queries